# How do you you scrape text that is part of a style element with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Im looking to gather information from a weather website ([www.windy.com](http://www.windy.com)) using selenium and python. So far I have successfully scraped almost everything I want using the following ID:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "detail-data-table")
```

All of this information is entered into an html table:

```
<table id="detail-data-table" class="grab" data-ref="dataTableTable" style="width: 1410px;"><tbody><tr class="td-days height-days"><td colspan="8" class="sticky-title-wrapper" data-day="2022-06-08"><div class="sticky-title" data-daydiv="2022-06-08">Wednesday 8</div></td><td colspan="8" class="sticky-title-wrapper" data-day="2022-06-09"><div class="sticky-title" data-daydiv="2022-06-09">Thursday 9</div></td><td colspan="8" class="sticky-title-wrapper" data-day="2022-06-10"><div class="sticky-title" data-daydiv="2022-06-10">Friday 10</div></td><td colspan="8" class="sticky-title-wrapper" data-day="2022-06-11"><div class="sticky-title" data-daydiv="2022-06-11">Saturday 11</div></td><td colspan="8" class="sticky-title-wrapper" data-day="2022-06-12"><div class="sticky-title" data-daydiv="2022-06-12">Sunday 12</div></td><td colspan="7" class="sticky-title-wrapper" data-day="2022-06-13"><div class="sticky-title" data-daydiv="2022-06-13">Monday 13</div></td></tr><tr class="td-hour height-hour d-display-waves"><td data-ts="1654678800000">2<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654689600000">5<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654700400000">8<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654711200000">11<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654722000000">2<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1654732800000">5<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1654743600000">8<small>PM</small></td><td class="day-end" data-ts="1654754400000">11<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1654765200000">2<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654776000000">5<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654786800000">8<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654797600000">11<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654808400000">2<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1654819200000">5<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1654830000000">8<small>PM</small></td><td class="day-end" data-ts="1654840800000">11<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1654851600000">2<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654862400000">5<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654873200000">8<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654884000000">11<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654894800000">2<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1654905600000">5<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1654916400000">8<small>PM</small></td><td class="day-end" data-ts="1654927200000">11<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1654938000000">2<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654948800000">5<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654959600000">8<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654970400000">11<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1654981200000">2<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1654992000000">5<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1655002800000">8<small>PM</small></td><td class="day-end" data-ts="1655013600000">11<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1655024400000">2<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1655035200000">5<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1655046000000">8<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1655056800000">11<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1655067600000">2<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1655078400000">5<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1655089200000">8<small>PM</small></td><td class="day-end" data-ts="1655100000000">11<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1655110800000">2<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1655121600000">5<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1655132400000">8<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1655143200000">11<small>AM</small></td><td data-ts="1655154000000">2<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1655164800000">5<small>PM</small></td><td data-ts="1655186400000">11<small>PM</small></td></tr><tr class="td-windCombined height-windCombined d-display-waves"><td style="background: linear-gradient(to right,rgb(0,224,172),rgb(0,224,172),rgb(0,233,113))"><div style="transform: rotate(126deg);
                -webkit-transform:rotate(126deg);">#</div>10<small>17</small></td><td style="background: linear-gradient(to right,rgb(0,233,113),rgb(0,236,57),rgb(23,205,254))"><div style="transform: rotate(120deg);
                -webkit-transform:rotate(120deg);">#</div>11<small>18</small></td><td style="background: linear-gradient(to right,rgb(23,205,254),rgb(244,244,244),rgb(213,239,245))"><div style="transform: rotate(167deg);
                -webkit-transform:rotate(167deg);">#</div>5<small>19</small></td><td style="background: linear-gradient(to right,rgb(213,239,245),rgb(23,205,254),rgb(0,211,224))"><div style="transform: rotate(171deg);
                -webkit-transform:rotate(171deg);">#</div>8<small>14</small></td><td style="background: linear-gradient(to right,rgb(0,211,224),rgb(0,224,172),rgb(0,211,224))"><div style="transform: rotate(154deg);
                -webkit-transform:rotate(154deg);">#</div>9<small>17</small></td><td style="background: linear-gradient(to right,rgb(0,211,224),rgb(0,211,224),rgb(23,205,254))"><div style="transform: rotate(154deg);
                -webkit-transform:rotate(154deg);">#</div>8<small>19</small></td><td style="background: linear-gradient(to right,rgb(23,205,254),rgb(118,222,250),rgb(213,239,245))"><div style="transform: rotate(150deg);
                -webkit-transform:rotate(150deg);">#</div>7<small>15</small></td><td class="day-end" style="background: linear-gradient(to right,rgb(213,239,245),rgb(213,239,245),rgb(213,239,245))"><div style="transform: rotate(129deg); 
...
```

and so on.

So it is convenient to scrape, the last piece of the puzzle is getting the wind direction. On the table the direction is represented by a # but the style name in the div has the wind direction in degrees. This is what I want.

```
<div style="transform: rotate(126deg);
                -webkit-transform:rotate(126deg);">#</div>
```

is there a way to grab just "126deg" from that style?

Comment: You could try using a regular expression to extract it

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="iconfont" style="transform: rotate(330deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(330deg);">"</div>
```

the code above is the full div element.

Just use By.Class:

```
search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS, "iconfront")
search = list(set(search))

for s in search:
    print(s.get_attribute("style"))
    #Use substring/index to isolate (330deg)

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please note that in your example, your <div> element didn't have the 'class' tag. When I entered the forecast website it was there.